# django overwrite form clean method

Tags: django, django-forms

When overwriting a form clean method how do you know if its failed validation on any of the fields? e.g.  in the form below if I overwrite the clean method how do I know if the form has failed validation on any of the fields?

```
class PersonForm(forms.Form):
    title = Forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = Forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = Forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = Forms.CharField(max_length=100)

def clean(self, value):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    IF THE FORM HAS FAILED VALIDATION:
        self.data['password'] = 'abc'
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have failed validation!")
    ELSE:
        return cleaned_data
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check if any errors have been added to the error dict:

```
def clean(self, value):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    if self._errors:
        self.data['password'] = 'abc'
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have failed validation!")
    else:
        return cleaned_data
```

BONUS! You can check for errors on specific fields:

```
def clean(self, value):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    if self._errors and 'title' in self._errors:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You call that a title?!")
    else:
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Hi Mark I am exactly using this procedure however the validation error is getting displayed on top of admin(change_form) page , How can i display the error message just above that field for which i am applying the validation. Thanks in advance

Comment: The simplest way to do that is to raise the validation error inside the `clean_<field_name>` for your field. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Hi Mark I have written this raise forms.ValidationError({'interview_type': ["error message",]}) but it is showing me the error message on top of change_form .Can you tell me what should i modify in this.

Comment: This is better asked as its own question rather than a comment.

Answer (score 5):

> If your data does not validate, your
>   Form instance will not have a
>   cleaned_data attribute

[Django Doc on Accessing "clean" data](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data)

Use `self.is_valid()`.

Comment: so would i just do a check on cleaned_data

e.g.

if not self.cleaned_data:
    #do something

Comment: No, the attribute doesn't exist, you would get an AttributeError. I extended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although its old post, if you want to apply validations on more than 1 field of same form/modelform use `clean()`. This method returns **cleaned_data** dictionary.

To show the errors to users you can use `add_error(<fieldname>, "your message")` method. This will show the errors along with the field name rather on top of the form. The example is shown below:

`add_error()` automatically removes the field from **cleaned_data** dictionary, you dont have to delete it manually. Also you dont have to import anything to use this.

[documentation is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

```
def clean(self):

  if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
    msg = 'passwords do not match'
    self.add_error('password2', msg)

  return self.cleaned_data
```

If you just want validation on single field of form/modelform use `clean_<fieldname>()`. This method will take the values from **cleaned_data** dictionary and then you can check for logical errors. Always return the value once you are done checking logic.

```
def clean_password(self):

  password = self.cleaned_data['password']

  if len(password)<6:
    msg = 'password is too short'
    self.add_error('password', msg)

  return password
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of overriding `clean()` in `django.forms.Form` and also using `django-braces` for `AnonymousRequiredMixin` to require that only anonymous users visit the Loing Page:

```
class LoginView(AnonymousRequiredMixin, FormView):
    """
    Main Login. And Social Logins
    """
    template_name = 'core/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:index')

    def get_success_url(self):
        try:
            next = self.request.GET['next']
        except KeyError:
            next = self.success_url
        return next

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        user = auth.authenticate(username=cd['login_username'], 
            password=cd['login_password'])
        if user:
            auth.login(self.request, user)
            messages.info(self.request, 'You are logged in.')
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```