# Django form with Dynamic fields. Invalid but no errors

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have been working with a Django form that can generate a number of fields dynamically according to the parameters passed in, as I have learnt from `SO`, like this:

```
 class Review_Form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sentences = kwargs.pop('sentences')
        super(Review_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        counter = 1
        for q in sentences:
             self.fields['review' + str(counter)] = forms.CharField(label='Review' + str(counter), required=False)
             counter += 1
```

As for the corresponding html, I pass the each field separately into `contest['block']`, where `block` is a list of dictionaries, with key value pair indicating the `ith` field of the form and the corresponding items I need.
So the html is as following:

```
<form action="{% url 'done_review' title%}" method="post">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    {% for b in block %}
                    <div class="8u">
                        <p> {{b.sent}} </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="4u">
                        <input class="front_form-control" value="{{b.text}}" type={{b.field}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit">Done Review
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Then, unfortunately, the form is not valid after I submit it. I tried to test it by printing the errors in `views.py`, like the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
     # do something
else:
     print form.errors, 'here1'
     print form.non_field_errors(), 'here2'
     field_errors = [(field.label, field.errors) for field in form]
     print field_errors, 'here3'
```

It prints out like this:

```
  here1
  here2
 [('Review1', []), ('Review2', []), ...many more... ('Review38', [])] here3
```

I really don't understand why the form is not valid and I have got stuck here for days and googled everywhere. Hope someone could help me here.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: `form.errors` are populated only after `form.is_valid()` is called. You have `required=False`, and not using any validator. What do you expect the form to do.

Comment: I expect that after a user fills in some (or none) of the fields, and click submit, I can get what the user fills in. I set `required=False` to allow some fields of the form not to be filled, and I do not use validator because I just need whatever the user fills in as a string. I am not sure if I am doing this in a right way..

Comment: if you create your attributes dinamically, try check them dinamically, you can rewrite the form clean function and check them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432489/django-overwrite-form-clean-method

Comment: Thanks @levi But I don't really understand how to check them. As the last answer of your link says, I cannot access clean_data when the form is not valid. So, sorry that I am not very experienced in django development, could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the problem is solved.
This happens because the form is unbound, because of one of my careless mistakes:

```
form = Review_Form(sentences=sents)
```

instead of what it should be:

```
form = Review_Form(request.POST, sentences=sents)
```

I answered this because I think this is probably useful for other new developers like me.
Read more on unbound and bound forms, if you like, from here: [Django form API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/)

Comment: You also have another problem, you have multiple instances of `{% csrf_token %}` because you put this tag in your for loop. You need to add this tag right after the `<form>` tag, or right before the `</form>` tag. Right now if you have 10 fields, you'll have 11 instances of `{% csrf_token %}`